# Send existing price to PayPal

Tags: php, paypal

Currently i have PayPal working on my website for booking venue's etc. I have the deposit (which is a set amount) being paid through PayPal and it works perfectly.

After the deposit is paid, the outstanding amount (the amount still to be paid) is saved into the database.

What i want to do is set the price of my PayPal button to be this outstanding amount when a customer wants to fully pay the outstanding amount.

However, I've looked around and can't find anything that specifically matches my description. I haven't even attempted this as i have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the Saved amount(stored in database) and pass it to the paypal button code.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="YOUR_PAYPAL_EMAIL">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="STORED_DATABASE_AMOUNT">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```